# After recovering from suspend, artifacts appear in text

Tags: xorg, fonts, suspend

I have Ubuntu Desktop 12.04 64-bit installed on my Panasonic CF-51 laptop (GPU: Intel 945GM). When I recover from suspend mode, artifacts appear in the text. These artifacts look random. This occurred even with a fresh install, fully updated, with no other programs installed.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to your question, at least it increases the chance of identifying the problem better.

Comment: @v2r I updated the post with a link to a screen shot.

Comment: It looks it's consistent with each character in a given font and style. Note the blue underlined hyparlinks. They are missing one line of pixels of text

Comment: Please confirm that your graphics card is an ATI X1300 (I looked it up but maybe there are several CF-51 models). Did you install a proprietary graphics driver?

Comment: Also, if you do CTRL-ALT-F1, should see a text console, then CTRL-ALT-F7 to return to GUI. Do you still get this artifacts?

Comment: In the image you are using firefox as the web browser, does this problem happen with any other browsers and does it happen anywhere else?

Comment: Going to the terminal and back did not change the artifacts.

Comment: I would guess it has nothing to do with the ATI drivers.
I'm using a Thinkpad X60s with Intel integrated graphics and it has the same problems:
after recovering from suspend, artefacts appear in text -- and the artefacts are consistent for each character.

Comment: I was only able to resolve this issue by returning to Windows. I tried using Ubuntu Desktop in 2008 and had other issues. Maybe in another 5 years it will be finally working properly.

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing the font. That might fix it.

System installed fonts are found here → /usr/share/fonts/

It looks like your using "Nimbus Sans L" font so just try re-installing them...

[How to install fonts in Ubuntu →](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-fonts-in-ubuntu#.UjqWFKxx1D0)

**"EDIT" ↓**

I am running Firefox in the image below, but check to see if you have the `"Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above"` checked. Here in Firefox → go to, edit, prefrences, content, click the <kbd>Avanced</kbd> tab under `Fonts & Colors` . see the pointer in image... If checked, un-check it and then check it back. This may reset it, and solve the problem.

Hope this helps...

[image]

**Edit #2**↓

Try downloading and installing: → [ATI binary X.Org driver](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/fglrx/)

Comment: It actually persists across different fonts and programs. The webpage is just an example.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: @Paul Try downloading and installing: ATI binary X.Org driver, from Ubuntu Software Center...